# I cannot use viewDidAppear and viewDidDisappear at the same project

Tags: ios, swift, uiwebview, viewdidappear

`radarMap` is a `UIWebView` object and `exitMapButton` is its close button. To access map I used hidden actions. Now I want to add fade out and fade in animations while hiding. I did fade in but not fade out. How can I add fade out animation while hiding?

```
func openRadarMap(){
        radarMap.hidden = false
        exitMapButton.hidden = false
        self.radarMap.alpha = 0
        self.exitMapButton.alpha = 0
        
    }
    
    override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
        
        if radarMap.hidden == false {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, animations: {
            self.radarMap.alpha = 1.0
            self.exitMapButton.alpha = 1.0
        }) }
    }
    
    func exitFromMap() {
        exitMapButton.hidden = true
        radarMap.hidden = true
        self.exitMapButton.alpha = 0.0
        self.radarMap.alpha = 0.0
    }
    
    
    
    override func viewDidDisappear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidDisappear(animated)
        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, animations: {
            self.radarMap.alpha = 0.0
            self.exitMapButton.alpha = 0.0
        })
    }
    
    @IBAction func exitMapButtonAction(sender: AnyObject) {
        exitFromMap()
    }
    
  
    
    @IBAction func webView(sender: UIButton) {
        getAd()
       openRadarMap()
        let URL = "somewebpage.com/map"
        let requestURL = NSURL(string:URL)
        let request = NSURLRequest(URL: requestURL!)
        radarMap.loadRequest(request)
        //performSegueWithIdentifier("mapView", sender: nil)
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The method `viewDidAppear` will be called after the view was removed from the  view hierarchy. the description of the method says ,

> Notifies the view controller that its view was removed from a view hierarchy.

So the view will not be actually visible at that time, I suggest you to write the fade out code in `viewWillDisappear`

Answer (score -1):

You need to call `super` in all cases. If you don't call super for `viewDidAppear:` you can't have `viewDidDisappear:` ever called.